# 301 redirection not working in my case

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a old url :

http://www.abc.com/search.php?id=12&name=amit

After some time i have made the changes(for proper url rewriting) in url and it became

http://www.abc.com/search.php?name=amit&id=12

The url rewriting of new url(changed url) is successfully done to

http://www.abc.com/amit-12

But the problem is, How I redirect 301 from old url (through htaccess)

http://www.abc.com/search.php?id=12&name=amit

to

new url

http://www.abc.com/amit-12

I have tried a lots but m unsuccessful..What should I do ?
Help.. Anybody!

Thanks !

Comment: Wait a minute! If your URI coming IN is /search.php?name=amit&id=12 (or id=12&name=amit, they're identical), .htaccess URL rewriting is not going to convert it to /amit-12 (your PHP can't use it). What you can do is take an INcoming URI of /amit-12 and rewrite it to /search.php?name=amit&id=12. Is that what you're doing? If so, please use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?id=([^&]*)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2-%1? [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to insert this rule **before all other rules**.